# How to run PHPStan in PhpStorm on Windows through WSL?

Tags: php, configuration, phpstorm, wsl-2, phpstan

I run PhpStorm 2023.1 on Windows 11. On the Windows machine, I have an Ubuntu WSL enabled, so that I can develop a PHP project, which works fine.

Now I wanted to enable PHPStan support yet I get the error:

```
phpstan: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

In the PHPStan settings within PhpStorm I have added the WSL config, and it validates:

[image: Screenshot of PHPStan run config]

I wanted to remove the `System PHP` config, yet the option is greyed out:

[image: the invalid PHPStan config for system PHP]

How to enable PHPStan support here?

Comment: System PHP Removal (unable to do that right now AFAIK) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-70523 and/or https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56550

Comment: What do you have for PHPStan at `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Quality Tools | PHP Stan` ? Have you tried selecting the right interpreter there? If that does not work -- make sure that this "Ubuntu-22.04" PHP Interpreter is selected as default for this project and then use "By default project interpreter" in PHPStan config at the aforementioned place. P.S. The latest is 2023.2.3 version

Comment: @LazyOne Default interpreter setting was the missing piece! Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you have for PHPStan at:

`Settings/Preferences | PHP | Quality Tools | PHPStan`?

Have you tried selecting the correct PHP interpreter there?

If you did and that still does not work then please do the following: make sure that this "Ubuntu-22.04" PHP interpreter is selected as **default for this project** and then use: `By default project interpreter` in PHPStan config at the aforementioned place.

[image]

---

Regarding **System PHP removal**.  It is not possible to do that right now (latest stable PhpStorm 2023.2.3 version).

Watch for issues [WI-70523](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-70523) and/or [WI-56550](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56550) tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.